# SharePoint 2007 to x64 bit hardware - Problem with SSP

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, shared-service-provider

I have a test farm that I'm upgrading to SP2 and moving to new x64 hardware in preparation for doing this in production (with a 2010 upgrade after that).

The entire process went fine - my test farm is up an running on the new hardware - with one major exception.  There is a problem in the restored SSP.  Even though I've reset the crawled content, run a full crawl, and verified that the AAM, search scopes and content source looks OK, when I attempt a search I get this message:

"Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings."

This is not making sense to me because search worked before the move.  I've run this error message through google but none of the answers seem to apply to my situation.

I'm thinking about recreating the SSP from scratch and seeing if that fixes it but I wanted to see if anyone had any thoughts.

Thanks,
brl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out there was a simple solution to this problem.  I was missing a couple of Managed Properties/Metadata properties and once I added those search is working again.  Hope that helps someone else.